# np.std(ddof=1) and statistics.pstdev given different answers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

[image][image]

```
population_std = np.std(final_array)
sample_std = np.std(final_array, ddof=1)  #  ??
print(population_std,sample_std)

sample_static_std = statistics.stdev(final_array,)
populate_stat_std = statistics.pstdev(final_array)  # ??
print(populate_stat_std,sample_static_std,sep=" <-----> ")
```

NP provide more correct values . but i need to know how do i get correct values from statistic lib. i think statistic lib automatically round up the number . how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

`pstdev`, by definition, is the *population* standard deviation. Also by definition, the population standard deviation has degree of freedom equal to zero. The sample `std`, on the other hand, has 1 degree of freedom.

In other words,

```
statistcs.pstdev(x) == np.std(x, ddof=0)
```

and

```
statistics.stdev(x) == np.std(x, ddof=1)
```

Comment: sir population part is completely OK . statistic and the np lib provide same answer but in the sample ,  answers are different  ( statistcs.pstdev(x) == np.std(x, ddof=0)  ==> False  )

Comment: You probably have a typo. Can you post a reproducible example?